# gdb only shows the function where the error occurred (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

My program returned a segfault, when I tried to use gdb it didn't help much

```
gdb ./a.out
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000406d74 in class::function() ()
bt
#0  0x0000000000406d74 in class::function() ()
#1  0x0000000000407893 in main ()
```

Not much else I could think of. Is there anything I could do with gdb to get more details that would actually help?

Comment: Did you compile with debug information (`-g` for gcc and clang)?

Comment: This actually did the trick, adding -g3 after "g++" and then running gdb shows exactly where the segfault happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a forgotten to include debug information in your binary. If you do this (by compiling with `-g` if you use `g++` or `clang++`, else read your compiler manual), the output of `bt` will show the important line numbers and `gdb` will be able to provide you with more information in general.